# How to upload a Pandas DataFrame into a Postgres table in Airflow?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-engineering

I need to create a task in Airflow which downloads data from one Postgres database and uploads it to another.

My code looks like this:

```
def task_data_upload():

    postgres_sql_download = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="a", schema="b")
    data = postgres_sql_download.get_pandas_df(''' SELECT * FROM table_name1 ''')

    postgres_sql_upload = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="c", schema="d")
    postgres_sql_upload.bulk_load('table_name2', data)
```

The table `table_name2` is created in a previous task, postgres_conn_id/schemas are fine, and `get_pandas_df` works as well. The problem seems to be in the last line - it doesn't upload the dataframe.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it can be done like this:

```
postgres_sql_upload = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='c', schema='d') 
postgres_sql_upload.insert_rows('table_name2', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for a bit of an different Approach:

- Pandas DataFrames provide a method `to_sql` which takes a sql alchemy engine as argument.

  - see [Pandas Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

In code this looked like:

```
postgres_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="conn_id")
df.to_sql('data_table', postgres_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine(), if_exists='replace', chunksize=1000)
```

As you can see I provided two additional parameters:

- if exists handles what to do if the table/data already exists
- chunk size commits the rows in chnunks which is great if you have larger amounts of data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Postgres Operator in Airflow to upload a Pandas Data Frame into a Postgres table.
step to follow

1. Install the psycopg2 library, which is required to connect to Postgres from Python.
2. Import the required libraries:
3. mport pandas as pd
   from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
4. Load your data into a Pandas DataFrame. For example, let's say your data is in a CSV file called data.csv:
   df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
5. Define the SQL statement to create the table in Postgres. The column names and data types in the SQL statement should match the columns in your Pandas DataFrame,